# RxJava: catch exception properly

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming

I am trying to perform some IO operation in the Schedulers IO thread, and if an exception is thrown, I want to show some Toast to the user.

For this I use the following code:

```
Observable.interval(0, 15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnNext(event -> new Repository().inputOutput(MainActivity.this);)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnError(throwable -> 
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show())
            .subscribe();
```

When an exception is thrown on method "inputOutput", I expect the Throwable to be catched in the "doOnError" consumer, but it doesn't happen and the exception is thrown to the surrounding code.

What am I doint wrong?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Why not catch it in subscribe()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should looks like this :

```
Observable.interval(0, 15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
              .flatMap(event -> new Repository().inputOutput(MainActivity.this);)        
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe({your onNext/onComplete handler}, throwable -> 
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()));
```

Comment: Please ask me, if you need more detail explanation

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :) I don't fully understand it though. Shouldn't the subscribeOn be on "mainThread" and observeOn "io" ? And also, what is wrong with my solution? Shouln't it work too? And why the flatMap?

Comment: Let me know - do you want keep all processing in background thread? If yes - in most cases you should subscribe on IO thread pool. You can read, for example https://medium.com/upday-devs/rxjava-subscribeon-vs-observeon-9af518ded53a. Why flatMap ? - You trying to use doOnNext operator. Basically it uses for creating side effects. If i understood you right -  you need to subscribe on result of new Repository().inputOutput(MainActivity.this). http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html

Comment: Yes, I want to keep procesing on background thread. I don't need to subscribe on the resulto of the inputOutput (in fact in my example I use it in a Consumer inside doOnNext, that doesn't return any result).

Comment: You can read this discussion : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rxjava/Tjz1lYKWDB0
Well, you can't handle error from side effects methods in manner, that you suggested. Solution, if you want handle errors from inputOutput - wrap inputOutput invocation into Single/Observable and use flatMap